# lualatex not correctly setting PDF page boxes?

Tags: luatex, pdf

I want to specify PDF page boxes using `lualatex`. But no version of Adobe Reader (`9.5.5 04/26/2013` under Linux; `DC 2018.011.20040` under Mac OS) or Acrobat Pro (`8.0.0` under Windows) I have access to seems to detect them. All of them have no problems with the files produced by `pdflatex`. What's wrong?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\setstocksize{300bp}{300bp}
\settrimmedsize{200bp}{200bp}{*}
\settrims{50bp}{50bp}
\setlrmarginsandblock{50bp}{50bp}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{50bp}{50bp}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \edef\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pagesattr}
  \edef\pdfcompresslevel{\pdfvariable compresslevel}
  \edef\pdfobjcompresslevel{\pdfvariable objcompresslevel}
\fi
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfpageattr{
  /MediaBox [0.0 0.0 300.0 300.0]
  /BleedBox [44.33071 44.33071 255.66929 255.66929]
  /TrimBox [50.0 50.0 250.0 250.0]
}
\trimLmarks
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

## Screenshots

These screenshots are taken with the 'Show art, trim, & bleed Boxes' option turned on.

### PDF produced by `lualatex`

[image]

### PDF produced by `pdflatex`

[image]

Comment: I upvoted the question, but nevertheless typos are “off-topic”, because they don't really help other readers who might face an actual problem.  I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I can just delete the question if that's better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue of the OP was caused by a typo and the solution (fixing the typo) is of little value for the community.

Comment: @DavidPurton No need to delete the question: It is a *good* question by the standards of this site (clearly stated problem, well carried out MWE, significant own research, ...), hence the upvotes. It is just that issue and answer provide only limited long-term value for the community, hence it will get closed. Don’t worry too much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a Typo in the `\pdfvariable` name: You want to set the `pageattr`, not the `pagesattr`. Your LuaTeX code sets the attributes in the PDF page**s** directory instead where they are ignored. So it works if you replace

```
  \edef\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pagesattr}
```

with

```
  \edef\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}
```

Comment: Oh! How embarrassing...